# How to render to another controller's action in Ruby on Rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, render

I'm trying to render from a `pnr` controller to the index of a `web_services` and I need to specify a layout as well.

I tried:

```
render :layout => "admin", :action => "web_services/index"
render :layout => "admin", :"web_services/index"
render :layout => "admin", :controller => "web_services", :action => "index"
```

and nothing works.

What should I use?

**RESOLVED**

**DONE!**
I had to use:

```
redirect_to :layout => "admin", :controller => 'web_services', :action => 'index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:layout` option for `redirect_to` is meaningless as redirect only needs a path and a status, and layout is just a name of the template. Also, as the name implies, `redirect_to` doesn't render anything, it tells the browser to go to another page. I suggest you to read the RoR guides at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to).